# using range-based for with std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>> deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11, set, unique-ptr, deleted-functions

I'm trying to use a range based iterator with a set of `unique_ptr` instances but I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

The basics of the code is below:

```
#include <set>
#include <memory>

std::set<std::unique_ptr<Component>>* m_components;

class Component
{
    void DoSomething(){};
};

void ProcessComponents()
{
    for (auto componentsIterator : *m_components)

    {
        componentsIterator->DoSomething();
        componentsIterator++;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this would be a problem or how to solve it?

Comment: `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Component>>*` - in all likelihood, the `set` itself doesn't need to be a pointer. Also, it's odd that you use a smart pointer to hold the elements within the `set` but decide to manage the `set`'s memory manually.

Comment: @Praetorian, the set is actually a member of a class that is initialized when the class is created and destroyed in the destructor.  I tried to create a simple example to illustrate my question.  It seemed like the right way but I'm a bit of a beginner so let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Component>> m_components` is the better way. It'll be instantiated and destroyed along with your class instances, and there's no need to `new` and `delete` it any more.

Comment: awesome!  thanks for the tip.  My first time posting here.  Just created an account and am already amazed at how responsive and how valuable a resource it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (auto componentsIterator : *m_components)
```

That `auto` expands to `std::unique_ptr<Component>`, which means that you are trying to take a *copy* of each element. IOW, that loop actually is:

```
for(auto it=m_components->begin(); it!=m_components->end(); ++it)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Component> componentsIterator=*it;
    componentsIterator->DoSomething();
    componentsIterator++;
}
```

As you can see, you are invoking `std::unique_ptr<Component>` copy constructor, but the copy constructor of `unique_ptr` is deleted (because it is against the `unique_ptr` semantic).

Use `auto &` to take a reference instead.

(BTW, `componentsIterator` there is not a sensible name, since it's not an iterator, it's the actual element)

Comment: thanks for the instant response.  it helps but doesn't quite get me there as I still get an error on the increment operator  C2676: binary '++' : 'const std::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: @jhegedus: what do you intend to do with that `++`? `unique_ptr` doesn't define any `++` operator, is it a thing of your `Component` class or you put it there to move to the next element in the loop?

Comment: I thought I needed the ++ to iterate through the loop.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @jhegedus: yes, you misunderstood; the range-based `for` already takes care of that.

Comment: actually, I see I misunderstood, that is in the for you expanded out for me.  Thanks again

Comment: @jhegedus: in general, remember that with the range-based `for` you don't need to care about iterators at all - it will just loop automatically over all the *elements* of the container, without you having to do anything special.